# Android List problem

Tags: android, android-listview

I've create an application using JSON. It shows the list of some items from one link whatever i used in Codes. In my application i've using 2 layouts for display the items. First layout doesn't have any problem. But, when i go to next layout the result of first layout also show here and overrides the second layout's contents. I'm using android:list for list that. Can anyone clarify this doubt? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you should post relevant code in support of your question..

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ID on your Lists are different. This could cause the problem.

Comment: hey i'm using inbuild list id (android:list)

Comment: Yeah, dont do that. It's only for very simple Views and you'll face a lot of limits. You might consider changing your design, use a xml-file with an empty ListView and populate it in your activity. This way you'll have much more control of your application.